# Java Spring редирект на предыдущую страницу

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Есть страница с контентом

```
@GetMapping("/tech")
    public String tech () {
    return "tech";
}
```

На этой странице есть вызов POST метода

```
@PostMapping("/ping")
    public String str (String ip, Map<String, Object> model) {
// --- code ---
    model.put("result", result);
    return "redirect:/tech";
}
```

Вопрос в том как вывести данные из `model.put("result", result);` на странице /tech, а не на /ping. Говоря по-другому сначала редирект, уже потом `model.put("result", result);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помещаем данные с использованием интерфейса RedirectAttributes:

```
@PostMapping("/ping")
   public String str (String ip, Map<String, Object> model, RedirectAttributes  ra) {
   // --- code ---
   ra.addFlashAttribute("result", result);
return "redirect:/tech";
}
```

Получаем страницу по нужному пути /tech и с результатами `"result", result`